# Trying to configure pystata on my pc but get the following error

Tags: python, stata

Trying to configure `pystata` on my PC but get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PathToPython\Python\Python39\site-packages\stata_setup.py", line 45, in config
    config.init(edition, splash=splash)
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'splash'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open **stata_setup.py**, replace line 45 with

```
config.init(edition)
```